# Using switches to change frequency of square wave in Verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, frequency, wave

I am trying to use the 8 switches on my `basys2` board to control the frequency of a square wave, yet I'm having trouble with the input part of it, as I do not know how to divide the clock using the binary value of the register that I have collected the states of the switches in.

I know that I need to divide `25000000/[input value]` in order to get the correct value for the counter. My question is:

**how can I divide `25000000` by the register which has the switch states stored inside of it such, as `input [7:0] SW`?**

Comment: A simple method, though giving asymmetric output, is a counter - an iterative adder with compare and reload or clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume your input is always a power of two, you can use shifting to the right. But if you want the full 255 possible resolutions, you need to implement a divider.

Some synthesis tools just synthesize a divider when you simply write 25000000/inputValue. For some others, you may have to do it yourself.

Alternatively, if you don't want to waste time for dividing, you can pre-calculate the values beforehand and use a counter:

```
case (inputValue)
  8'b0000_00010: counterMax = 25000000/2 ; //Where 25000000/2 can be calculated at compile time or by you
  8'b0000_00011: counterMax = 25000000/3 ; //Where 25000000/3 can be calculated at compile time or by you
... 
endcase
```

and then just count to the counterMax:

```
always @(posedge clock)
begin
  counter <= counter + 1;
  if(counter == counterMax) begin
    out <= ~out;
    counter <= 0;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dividing by input, can you just increment your counter by `SW` each clock cycle? Then if SW is for example, '15', then your period is reduced by 15x, but you avoid an expensive division circuit.